# Proving the order relation in $\mathrm{PA}$ is total.

Tags: logic, peano-axioms

Let $\mathrm{PA}$ be the first order logic axioms of Peano Arithmetic. Define an order relation by:
$$
x\leq y\; \text{ if }\; (\exists z)(x+z=y).
$$ 
Can it be proved that this relation is total?

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, the main axiom for proving universal statements in PA is the induction scheme. Not all arguments require induction, but most nontrivial ones do. So that is your go-to axiom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can prove the formula $(\exists z: x+z=y)\vee (\exists z: y+z=x)$ by induction on $x$, say. In the induction step, consider the two cases $\exists z: x+z=y$ or $\exists z: y+z=x$. In the first case, pick $z$ with $x+z=y$. If $z=0$, then $x=y$, so $\exists z: y+z=x+1$ holds (take $z=1$). If $z=z^{\prime}+1$, then $(x+1)+z^{\prime}=y$, so $\exists z: (x+1)+z=y$ holds. In the second case, $y+z=x$ implies $y+(z+1)=x+1$, so again $\exists z: y+z=x$ holds.